# regex to replace '\\' by <br> but only outside some tags

Tags: html, regex, replace, latex, mathjax

I am new to regex and have been struggling for a while on this one: I want to transform LaTeX files to HTML.

I use mathjax to render equations and some javascript replace functions to convert the tags. I have nearly finished, but I still have an issue with the line breaks: I need to transform `\\` to `<br>`, but **only** outside the tags `\begin{array}` and `\end{array}`.

Example: in this portion, only the `\\` before `Montrer l'equivalence` should be replaced.

```
$M=\left(
\begin{array}{c|c}
A &B \\ \hline
C &D \\ 
\end{array}
\right)$

$in$ $\mathcal{M}_{n}(\mathbb{K})$ avec $A$ $\in$ $\mathcal{M}_{r}(\mathbb{K})$ inversible.\\ Montrer l'equivalence:
\[
\Bigl( rg(A) = rg(M)  \Bigr) \Leftrightarrow \Bigl( D = CA^{-1}B \Bigr)
\]


\begin{enumerate} 
\item Calculer $detB$ en fontion de $A$. 
\item En déduire que $detB \geqslant 0$.
\end{enumerate}

$M=
\left(
\begin{array}{c|c}
A &B \\ \hline
C &D \\ 
\end{array}
\right)$
```

How can I do this with regex ?

EDIT: I have found  [here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=&input=Soit%20%0A%24M%3D%0A%5Cleft%28%0A%5Cbegin%7Barray%7D%7Bc%7Cc%7D%0AA%20%26B%20%5C%5C%20%5Chline%0AC%20%26D%20%5C%5C%20%0A%5Cend%7Barray%7D%0A%5Cright%29%24%0A%0A%24in%24%20%24%5Cmathcal%7BM%7D_%7Bn%7D%28%5Cmathbb%7BK%7D%29%24%20avec%20%24A%24%20%24%5Cin%24%20%24%5Cmathcal%7BM%7D_%7Br%7D%28%5Cmathbb%7BK%7D%29%24%20inversible.%5C%5C%20Montrer%20l%27equivalence%3A%0A%5C%5B%0A%5CBigl%28%20rg%28A%29%20%3D%20rg%28M%29%20%20%5CBigr%29%20%5CLeftrightarrow%20%5CBigl%28%20D%20%3D%20CA%5E%7B-1%7DB%20%5CBigr%29%0A%5C%5D%0A%0A%0A%5Cbegin%7Benumerate%7D%20%0A%5Citem%20Calculer%20%24detB%24%20en%20fontion%20de%20%24A%24.%20%0A%5Citem%20En%20d%C3%A9duire%20que%20%24detB%20%5Cgeqslant%200%24.%0A%5Cend%7Benumerate%7D%0A%0A%24M%3D%0A%5Cleft%28%0A%5Cbegin%7Barray%7D%7Bc%7Cc%7D%0AA%20%26B%20%5C%5C%20%5Chline%0AC%20%26D%20%5C%5C%20%0A%5Cend%7Barray%7D%0A%5Cright%29%24) a handy regex tester...

Comment: Do you use a language for that or an editor?

Comment: Compiling one language into another is not just about regular expressions. It is about lexical and grammatical analysis.
The only thing i could suggest you is the use of [Lex & Yacc](http://epaperpress.com/lexandyacc/).
But this is a huge topic.

Comment: Sorry it's not clear, I'm not just starting to do this, I have nearly finished. I use a combination of javascript replace functions + mathjax to render equations. The `<br>` issue is the last issue I need to handle (at least, that's what I think!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this pattern in a replace with a callback function that return the first capture group or `<br>` when it is void:

```
/(\\begin{array}(?:[^\\]+|\\(?!end{array}))*\\end{array})|\\\\/
```

The idea is to match `\begin{array}...\end{array}` before `\\` to avoid to find `\\` inside `\begin{array}...\end{array}`.

detail:

```
(?:                   # open a non-capturing group
    [^\\]+            # all characters but \ 1 or more times
  |                   # OR
    \\(?!end{array})  # \ not followed by "end{array}"
)*                    # close non-capturing group, zero or more times
```

This structure is more efficient than a simple `.*?` that need many backtracks to succeed. It's a bit longer but more performant since it avoids lazy quantifiers.

*(ps: remove the delimiters `/` in regexpal)*